# Handle runtime screen resolution changes

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

In some new Android 7.0 firmwares there's an option to changes screen resolution (e.g. Android 7.0 firmware for S7 Edge has option to switch display resolution during runtime from qhd / fhd / hd).

My debugging attempts show that there's no config change coming (since my app properly handles language change, but not resolution change).

How to handle this kind of configuration change properly?

Comment: What do you mean by "there's no config change coming"? Also, what is your `targetSdkVersion`?

Comment: @CommonsWare targetSdkVersion = 23. Mean there seems no onConfigChange() callback.

Comment: See Ian's answer. Since your `targetSdkVersion` is 23, your process should be terminated when the user changes the zoom level, and your activity will be re-created (along with a fresh process) when the user returns to your app.

Comment: @CommonsWare any idea how to detect and handle screen res change for an app widget?

Comment: @drmrbrewer: That's a good question -- I haven't experimented with that particular combination. Ideally, `onAppWidgetOptionsChanged()` would be called at some point, as with an app widget resize operation, but I have no idea if it is.

Comment: @CommonsWare I already do a widget redraw when `onAppWidgetOptionsChanged()` is called (if the widget size has changed... which I determine by comparing `newOptions.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_WIDTH)` etc with the previous values), and some users still report that the widget goes blank.  I'm not sure how to test this, since my own test devices don't offer screen res change.

Comment: `OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_WIDTH` and kin are in `dp`, so they would not change based on screen zoom. You may need to keep track of the last-seen screen density (via `Configuration` or perhaps `DisplayMetrics`) and redraw in `onAppWidgetOptionsChanged()` if the density is different. "my own test devices don't offer screen res change" -- they don't offer "Display size" in Settings (e.g., in the Display category)?

Comment: @CommonsWare there is a "screen zoom".  When I apply that, my `onAppWidgetOptionsChanged()` reports that `newWidgetSize = 304|483|97|156` (`MIN_WIDTH|MAX_WIDTH|MIN_HEIGHT|MAX_HEIGHT`) and `oldWidgetSize = 344|555|113|185`, so there is a change in size based on those params, and the widget does redraw.

Comment: @CommonsWare P.S. a user reports that "the widget disappears when I switch to FHD+ or WQHD+" -- is that different to the "screen zoom" I mentioned?  It seems to me like it's different.

Comment: @drmrbrewer: Beats me, sorry. This is one of the issues with device manufacturers changing things in core Android operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the [Screen Zoom documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#screen-zoom):

> - If an app targets API level 23 or lower, the system automatically kills all its background processes. This means that if a user switches away from such an app to open the Settings screen and changes the **Display size** setting, the system kills the app in the same manner that it would in a low-memory situation. If the app has any foreground processes, the system notifies those processes of the configuration change as described in [Handling Runtime Changes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html), just as if the device's orientation had changed.
> - If an app targets Android 7.0, all of its processes (foreground and background) are notified of the configuration change as described in [Handling Runtime Changes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html).

Similarly to [handling configuration changes for multi-window](https://medium.com/google-developers/5-tips-for-preparing-for-multi-window-in-android-n-7bed803dda64#45fd), you should make sure you handle the following `configChanges`:

```
android:configChanges="screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|orientation"
```

Comment: Handling configuration changes seems to be geared around *activities*.  I have a homescreen *widget* that needs to re-draw itself should there be a screen resolution change.  I have some users reporting that the widget disappears on changing resolution, and I suspect I can solve this just by re-drawing the widget... but how is the widget notified?

Comment: @drmrbrewer - widgets are sent a callback to [onAppWidgetOptionsChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html#onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(android.content.Context,%20android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle)) when their size changes.

Answer (score 1):

I found that a non-documented flag `density` is required to be set in `configChanges` for the activity in Android 7 in order to survive the Screen Zoom.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|fontScale|density"
```