# UI elements don't scale (refresh) when device resolution is changed

Tags: c#, maui

Project: Default Maui project, net7.0
Device: Samsung s8+

Attached Screen

[image: 1]

What I do and what happens:

1. Build app to *.apk format, upload and install on the device,
2. Set the device resolution to WQHD+(2960x1440),
3. Run the app,
4. All looks fine. Left side of the attached screenshot,
5. Minimize the app and change the resolution to HD+ (1480x720),
6. Maximize the app. It looks like UI elements were not refreshed. Right side of the attached screenshot.

Problem does not exist when I first close the app then change the resolution and run the app again. In that scenario pages (views) look the same regardless resolution set - both look like the one on the left side of the screenshot.

How can I automatically refresh UI when device resolution is changed without restarting the application?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73917923/199364

Comment: Did you test this on the other devices? In addition, you can refer to this case about [Handle runtime screen resolution changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41884313/handle-runtime-screen-resolution-changes).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems to be a bug in Maui that came from Xamarin. In my example, described above, when screen resolution changes, the **density** also changes. Application (layout) is then re-drawn using device new screen resolution (width and height) but calculations are made with the **old value of density**. Seems there is no workaround for this but restarting the app.

More to be found here:
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7239
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/15080